# How can I proxy a WebSocket request while using Webpack dev server and HMR?

Tags: webpack, websocket, proxy, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I am using Webpack to build a React frontend while running the backend as a separate process and proxying the requests to it using Webpack dev server. The regular API requests proxy just fine but when I try to add any proxy using the `ws: true` option, then I start getting the following error and stack trace repeating every second after loading the page served by Webpack dev server on localhost.

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Upgrading to WebSocket
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] WebSocket error: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
<e>     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
<e>     at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:319:11)
<e>     at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
<e>     at Sender.sendFrame (C:\code\line-up\line-up-client\node_modules\ws\lib\sender.js:469:20)
<e>     at Sender.close (C:\code\line-up\line-up-client\node_modules\ws\lib\sender.js:197:12)
<e>     at WebSocket.close (C:\code\line-up\line-up-client\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:300:18)
<e>     at Receiver.receiverOnConclude (C:\code\line-up\line-up-client\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1114:18)
<e>     at Receiver.emit (node:events:527:28)
<e>     at Receiver.controlMessage (C:\code\line-up\line-up-client\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:582:14)
<e>     at Receiver.getData (C:\code\line-up\line-up-client\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:429:42) {
<e>   code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
<e> }
```

My proxy configuration is the following:

```
proxy: {
    '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5150',
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
    },
    '/ws': {
        target: 'ws://localhost:5150',
        ws: true,
    }
},
```

My backend listens to regular HTTP API requests on `http://localhost:5150` and the WebSocket endpoint is at `localhost:5150/ws`.

Things I have tried:

- Setting the target of the `/ws` proxy to use `http` protocol.
- Setting the target of the `/ws` proxy to go to the `/ws` path.
- Setting `ws: true` on both proxy objects.
- Various other permutations.

My client source code is not the one initiating the failing WebSocket connection, that code is removed and the error persists.

An excerpt from my `package.json` showing the relevant versions:

```
"webpack": "^5.72.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
```

EDIT:

It turns out the error loop comes from me trying to proxy the path that Webpack dev server uses to do the HMR. Changing the config and endpoint to use `/websocket` instead of `/ws` and changing the proxy to:

```
'/websocket': {
    target: 'http://localhost:5150',
    ws: true,
}
```

I'm getting a Websocket connection error in the client instead. I have a static vanilla JS page I use for testing the backend without Webpack which works fine so I presume the issue is with Webpack/client code somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

hmm...

share my case.

I am runngin react app (sub frontend app) on http 8080 port

Major frontend app running other port

And Httpd serve all apps by name-based virtualhost.

(hosts file is edited)

1. open major app "https://majorapp.mydomain.com"
2. click button to open sub app "https://subapp.mydomain.com"
3. got same error like "Websocket ..."

I Think webpack-dev-server package is make error

so edit "/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/parseURL.js" file

add a Line to 38 Line

options.protocol = window.location.protocol.includes('https') ? 'wss' : 'ws'

and patch it (check it "patch-package" package on npmjs.org)

and run webpack-dev-server again !